# Symyfony 3.4 - How to move entitiy to other database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am running a `Symfony 3.4` based web service using `Doctrine` to manage and persist the different data entities.

Now I am trying to implement a method which transfers older, abandoned user accounts to another database which acts as archive.

Regarding to the Symfony docs it should be no problem to configure Doctrine to manage different database connections and entity managers.

However I do not completely understand the process on how to setup this use case:

- Assume the Symfony project has different data entities `DataEntity1`, `DataEntity2`, etc. and different infrastructure entities `Infrastructure1`, etc..
- How to tell Doctrine to initialize the archive DB with the data entities only?
- How to move the entities between the DBs? Is loading them from entity manager 1 and persisting them in entity manger 2 the correct way?
- Is there any best practice on how to do this?

Comment: just from a general viewpoint I'd suggest to indeed set up different entity managers to handle your 'ongoing business' but strongly suggest not to rely on ORM but DBAL only when it comes to moving entities around if not even CRON based SQL script. I'd always try to avoid database maintenance done within my application code. just my two cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use the prefix option for the mapping configuration.

> prefix
>
> A common namespace prefix that all entities of this mapping share.
>   This prefix should never conflict with prefixes of other defined
>   mappings otherwise some of your entities cannot be found by Doctrine.
>   This option defaults to the bundle namespace + Entity, for example for
>   an application bundle called AcmeHelloBundle prefix would be
>   Acme\HelloBundle\Entity.

Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html it shoul help you.

To move the entities between the two DBs, you should have two entity managers and use the correct one to persist olders accounts.

Hope this helps.